# Cannot use named range when it is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range lstVendors that refers to: =OFFSET(Data!$W$2,0,0,COUNTA(Data!$W$2:$W$400),1). I want this range to be populated when the workbook opens. I have the following code for this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
Dim rslt()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim startRng As Range
Dim DropDown1 As DropDown

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("TextBox 6").Visible = False
'    Range("lstVendors").Offset(0, 0).Value = "Please Select..."
'    Set DropDown1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").DropDowns("Drop Down 1")
'    DropDown1.Value = 1
On Error Resume Next
If Not IsError(Range("lstVendors")) Then
    Range("lstVendors").ClearContents
End If
On Error GoTo 0
rslt = Application.Run("SQLite_Query", "path/to/my/sqlite", "SELECT PROGRAM_ID FROM VENDOR;")
Set startRng = Range("lstVendors")
i = 0
For n = 2 To UBound(rslt)
    Range("lstVendors").Offset(i, 0).Value = rslt(n)(0)
    i = i + 1
Next n
End Sub
```

It errors on the Set startRng = Range("lstVendors"). I know this is because there's nothing in the range when I'm trying to set it, because if I put one entry into the named range, the set works, however, I need it populated by the sqlite query on each open as the data changes.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Also, I'm not sure your `On Error Resume Next` is used appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, it's a Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. It's basically thinking that the named range doesn't exist because it's blank. Application.Goto Worksheets("Data").Range("lstVendors") returns the same error.

Comment: Is the error because your sql is returning no results, so it's invalidating the COUNTA portion of your formula?  If so, try wrapping that in a Max statment, like this:  =OFFSET(Data!$W$2,0,0,MAX(COUNTA(Data!$W$2:$W$400),2),1)

Comment: @Methonis the range doesn't exist after you clear it.  The `Name` does exist, but the range doesn't.  You don't need it in the code, anyways. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. Here is what I ended up doing in order to get around my problem. It involves adding something I didn't specify would be ok in my original question, so David's answer is great if what I did isn't an option. I first populated the first two cells in my named range with "Please Select..." and "All". In Sub Workbook_Open() we do this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
Dim rslt()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim startRng As Range
Dim DropDown1 As DropDown

' Disable our not found message
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("TextBox 6").Visible = False
' Set our start range to our named range
Set startRng = Range("lstVendors")
' Grab all vendor names
rslt = Application.Run("SQLite_Query", "path/to/my/sqlite", "SELECT PROGRAM_ID FROM VENDOR;")
' Print result. Skip first two rows as constants "Please Select..." and "All" are populated there
i = 2
For n = 2 To UBound(rslt)
    startRng.Offset(i, 0).Value = rslt(n)(0)
    i = i + 1
Next n
End Sub
```

Then we will create Sub Workbook_BeforeClose:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
' Disable the save changes dialog. This workbook will be locked up for display only. No need to confuse the user.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Clear everything below the "Please Select..." and "All" cells in the named range
On Error Resume Next
Range("lstVendors").Offset(2, 0).ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
' Save the changes to the named range
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This information is going to populate a drop down, so having Please Select and All hardcoded into the named range is acceptable for me. If that stipulation doesn't work for someone else looking at this in the future, please use David's suggestion! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have a dynamic range that doesn't evaluate after you clear the contents.  To avoid this, there are probably several ways, but easy to simply hardcode the `startRange` variable so that it always points to `Data!$W$2` address, which is (or rather, will become) the first cell in your `lstVendors` range.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim rslt()
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim startRng As Range
Dim DropDown1 As DropDown
Dim rngList As Range

'// Define your startRange -- always will be the first cell in your named range "lstVendors"
'   hardcode the address because the dynamic range may not evalaute.
Set startRange = Sheets("Data").Range("W2")

'// Empty th lstVendors range if it exists/filled
On Error Resume Next
    Range("lstVendors").Clear
On Error GoTo 0

'// Run your SQL query
rslt = Application.Run("SQLite_Query", "path/to/my/sqlite", "SELECT PROGRAM_ID FROM VENDOR;")
i = 0

'// Print results to the Worksheet, beginning in the startRange cell
For n = 2 To UBound(rslt)
    'Increment from the startRange cell
    startRange.Offset(i, 0).Value = rslt(n)(0)
    i = i + 1
    'Verify that "lstVendors" is being populated
    Debug.Print Range("lstVendors").Address
Next n


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, David. This works, although I was hoping Excel would have provided a way to still use the name ranged. Doing it this way, it somewhat eliminates the point of a named range since you have to reference a specific cell location first (meaning that if I ever change the start of my named range, I'll have to change the VBA too). However, I don't see any way around it from everything I've tried.

Comment: @Methonis did you see my suggestion above, wrapping the counta in a Max reference: =OFFSET(Data!$W$2,0,0,MAX(COUNTA(Data!$W$2:$W$400),2),1)

Comment: @sous2817 The sql statement returns the expected result. I think I've come across an alternate solution. Will post in a few. Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: The alternative is to create a named dynamic range which will always evaluate to a valid range reference.  Then you can use it.  But your reference is invalid -- it reduces to `Range("W2").Resize(0,0)`.  You could maybe (I haven't tried yet) try `Range("lstVendors").Resize(n,1).Offset(i, 0) = ...`. Not sure how that would work or if it would work with the dynamic range.

Comment: Edit: nope, that doesn't work either, because the range is dynamic, it's really evaluating to `Nothing.Resize(0,0)` or `Nothing.Offset(1,0)` - which can't compile (offset from *what*???).  You can't use range methods when the range object is `Nothing`.  Cheers.